# In building volatility curve for etf options, should I use synthetic forward price or cash price

Tags: implied-volatility, black

Assuming option market moves faster than ETF cash price in intraday high frequency setting. That means at each time point, when implied volatility is calculated by black-schole model by using cash ETF price, that is a small portion of dIV (change of IV) is due to that ETF price hasnt caught up with option price.

So in this sense, I feel that if I want to build a volatility curve on etf, I should in fact use synthetic forward price from put-call parity and employ black formula?

Not very sure if my understanding is correct.